# Mutex as class member using pthreads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have three classes, let's call them A, B and HardwareDriver. There is one instance of each of the classes. a and b run in two different threads. They both access the Hardware via an instance of HardwareDriver. Something like:

```
Class A {
... };

Class B {
... };

Class HardwareDriver {
    public:
        int accessHardware();
};

A a;
B b;
HardwareDriver hd;
pthread_t aThread;
pthread_t bThread;

main() {
    pthread_create(&aThread, NULL, &A::startA, &a);
    pthread_create(&bThread, NULL, &B::startB, &b);

    while (...) { };
    return 0;
}
```

The hardware can't be accessed by a and b at the same time, so I need to protect the code with a mutex. I'm new to multithreading but intuitively I would lock the mutex in the method of A and B right before it requests the hardware access by calling the method hd.accessHardware().

Now I'm wondering if it's possible, to perform the locking in hd.accessHardware() for more encapsulation. Would this still be thread safe?

Comment: Are a&b or threads uses same object of HardwareDriver? If yes then make sure only one object of HardwareDriver gets created. It will be safe if you use single object in both threads

Comment: I would only do the locking/unlocking in A/B if I was sure there aren't other classes that need to synchronize access to the shared resource, and if accessHardware is called heavily in a non-multithreaded context, in which case a mutex might add some overhead. Sounds implausible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would lock the mutex in the method of `A` and `B` right before it requests the hardware access by calling the method `hd.accessHardware()`.

This creates a risk of forgetting to lock that mutex prior to calling `hd.accessHardware()`.

> Now I'm wondering if it's possible, to perform the locking in `hd.accessHardware()` for more encapsulation. Would this still be thread safe?

That removes the risk of forgetting to lock that mutex and makes your API harder to misuse. And that would still be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have a mutex in your HardwareDriver class and have a critical section inside your class method. It would still be safe. Just remember that if you copy the object, you will also have a copy of mutex.

Comment: HardwareDriver should have a private copy constructor/assignment operator to prevent any accidental copying - and the mutex must (obviously) not be declared locally, but as a member of HardwareDriver

Answer (score 0):

When doing multithread programming in C/C++ you should ensure that data that is accessed by any of your thread for **WRITING** is locked when you do any *READ* or *WRITE* operation, you can leave lockfree *READONLY* datas.

The lock operations must have the smaller scope possibile, if TWO objects access a single resource you need a **SINGLE** semaphore/mutex, using two will expose you to dangerous [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

So, in your example you should add a mutex inside the *HardwareDriver* class and lock/unlock it everytime you read/write any class data.

You do not need to lock local data (stack allocated local variables) and you do not need locking on [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)) methods.

Since you are writing C++ and we are in 2017, I suppose you could use, and suggest you to use *std::thread* and *std::mutex* instead of pthread directly. In Linux the C++ native thread support is a tiny wrapper over pthreads so the overhead of using them is negligible also in embedded targets.